# Inserting Auto Generated PHP Code from PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I utilize the prepared statements of PHP code that PHPMYADMIN creates when you insert code into SQL?

I'm using a SQL statement that displays the date in particular column in a paticular format.

**PHP:**

$sql = 'SELECT TIME_FORMAT(last_update, "%l:%i:%s %p") FROM mytable';

**MYSQL:**

SELECT TIME_FORMAT( last_update,  "%l:%i:%s %p" ) 
FROM myTable;

LIMIT 0 , 30

**I understand that $sql is a variable... But how should I utilize this variable? How do I "run" this statement so the format will display correctly?**

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql =  'SELECT TIME_FORMAT(last_update, "%l:%i:%s %p") FROM mytable';
```

in above statement `$sql` variable contains only your sql string

you need to user some php functions provide to user sql database intraction

first fetch the result of the query like this

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

now fetch every row from `$result`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   //$row is a array contains your field values
}
```

before all of above  you need to make a  connection from database

```
$conn = mysql_connect("db_hostname", "db_username", "db_password") ;
mysql_select_db("db_name", $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

They're generated to make it easy to copy and paste if you're developing an application. You don't need to do anything specific with it; it's just there to make things easier if you're in that situation. Satish Sharma did a good job of explaining how exactly you'd use the PHP code. Basically if you're working in a situation where you'd need PHP or SQL code, you can just copy and paste from within phpMyAdmin once you've generated a query you like. I guess the simplest response is "if you don't know, you don't need it".